# Browser keeps losing javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

I'm having a very strange problem. I just bought a new computer running Windows 8, downloaded xampp, installed an apache server, everything's fine, blah blah. I made a basic HTML page that links to a JavaScript file and jQuery. Everything will work fine for a while, then I'll refresh the page and my browser can no longer find the jQuery file (I'm using Firefox v.17 if that helps). I'll view the source, click the link to view the jQuery file, and I'll get the error, "File not found." If I delete my browser cache and refresh the page everything works again, my browser can find jQuery.

Both jQuery and my JS file are located in the same folder. My browser can always find my JS file, it's just jQuery that it keeps "losing."

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it. This is quite frustrating. :/

**Update**
This is what's on my HTML page. Just basic code. :/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of this html file, especially showing how it's linking to the javascript and jquery files?

Comment: Do you have any particular cache settings in htaccess or similar for your XAMPP setup?

Comment: No, I'm just using the default settings. I've never had this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Is internet access always available?  Try:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually no. Could being disconnected from the internet be a problem? I didn't think it would matter since all the files are hosted on my computer.